# Required to Declare Primary Keys on Junction Table?

Tags: sql

In a junction table made up of only foreign keys (e.g. `ShopSupplier` in the example below), must we also declare those columns as primary keys in the DDL create statement? If yes, what would be the point of doing so? I would argue that these are NOT primary keys in the example below

```
CREATE TABLE Shop
(
    ShopID TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, 
    ShopName TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier
(
    SupplierID TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, 
    SupplierName TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE ShopSupplier
(
    ShopID TEXT,
    SupplierID TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(ShopID) REFERENCES Shop(ShopID),  
    FOREIGN KEY(SupplierID) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID)
);
```

The question again: Should I also declare `PRIMARY KEY(ShopID, SupplierID)` for the `ShopSupplier` table. If so, why? I would argue that there should be no primary key for that table.

Comment: You are right you can use them as a compound primary key. No need to add an artificial one

Comment: Should I also declare PRIMARY KEY(ShopID, SupplierID) for the ShopSupplier table. If so, why? I would argue that there should be no primary key for that table

Comment: If you don't have a PK you could add the same (shopid, supplierid) combination multiple times - probably not something you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both columns are foreign key, because they are referencing to other tables. In the case that only single connection between specific rows of `Shop`and `Supplier` may exit, you can use a unique constraint or create a combined primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE ShopSupplier(
  ShopID TEXT,
  SupplierID TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(ShopID, SupplierID),
  FOREIGN KEY(ShopID) REFERENCES Shop(ShopID),  
  FOREIGN KEY(SupplierID) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierID));
```

Then, both columns are foreign keys and belonging to the primary key.

In general setting the columns of a (pure) junction table as primary key isn't necessary. You may use it as a constraint to prohibit duplicates.

Comment: Thank you macmoonshine. Would we say that ShopID and SupplierID are primary keys of the ShopSupplier table though?

Comment: They are belonging to a compound primary key in this case. The primary key consists of two columns. In opposite to foreign keys, a table may have only one primary key at most.

Comment: Should I also declare PRIMARY KEY(ShopID, SupplierID) for the ShopSupplier table. If so, why? I would argue that there should be no primary key for that table

Comment: No, you should only declare one for this table, if you really need it. BTW.: You should think about abstract primary keys for the other tables. In practice, these lead to far fewer problems. Concrete keys are unnecessarily complicated, especially for foreign keys in the case of updates.

Comment: I was looking for the word "junction". Thank you, that all makes sense!